# How to import csv integers

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to import around 1000 data I can't do it one by one.
Is there a way to make the csv files import as integers instead of strings? It always changes to string when I use mongoimport.

Mongoimport --host localhost -- db database -- collection -- collections -- type csv -- file. 1000data.csv --headerline

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this from version 3.4, check out here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--columnsHaveTypes

Comment: So it will be :   mongoimport-- host localhost --db database --collection collections -- type csv -- file 1000data.csv --numInsertionWorkers int --writeConcern <1000> --headerline.    Is that correct?